# Minimum pulley diameter at small scale

Tags: pulleys

I am trying to design a musical locket which includes a slowly (28 rpm) rotating component.
The two things that make this a challenge is:

- Very limited space. The motor and the reduction system should fit in a cylindrical space of radius x height = 7.5cm x 2.5cm (3x1 inch).
- It must be as quiet as possible
- I don't have a specification for torque, but because of the lightweight components and the large reduction, I believe any solution sort of a watch mechanism will be overkill in that aspect

What I've got until now: Most motors and/or gearboxes readily online are very noisy. So my current plan is to use a computer fan, which is really silent. My first try was to use a 2-step worm reduction, but I noticed that although the motor itself was silent, the gears and the bearings their axles were on started producing large noise. So my current plan is to use a 1-step pulley reduction.

Now, I need to squeeze as large a ratio as possible from this, and then the rest of the reduction will come from feeding a PWM signal to the motor for descreased rotational speed. What I have not found anywhere is information on minimum pulley diameter at such scales.

**How small a diameter can a pulley be, if it is using a 2mm(~.01 inch) cross-sectioned "belt"?** Light scientific backing will be very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at some catalogs for a rough idea, perhaps... [Here is one](https://www.sdp-si.com/products/miniature-products/miniature-belts-and-pulleys-metric.php)

Comment: A 2 mm belt seems huge.

Comment: Computer fans are just quiet  because they are low power. Any similar sized brushless motor should just as quiet. BLDCs also require multi-phase drive electronics. Fans have them inside and won't run without them. Belt drive is the way to go for quietness but not compactness. I think you really should be looking at watch mechanisms. Nylon gears would be what I would try first.